# Is it unsafe to drive with a leak in exhaust box center silencer?

Tags: exhaust

I have a 5mm in diameter hole/leak in my exhaust center silencer box. The part seem to be wearing with other tiny leaks developing.  I plan to sell the car in 6 months at the latest.  The center silencer is after the cat.

Would it be unsafe from a health perspective to be driving around with this hole for up to 6 months or is it unlikely to be a real problem?  I really don't want to spend on it unless needed.

Comment: If it does not meet the standards required for use on the road (mot, Construction & Use regs) then it should be repaired.

Comment: If you have a hole in the box now, there is a good chance the exhaust will be ready to fall off in another 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *unlikely* to be a health concern directly - but that's not to say it's safe. Far from it.

A 5mm hole is pretty big - and with the signs of other leaks developing in the same region I'd say it's well on it's way to parting company with the rest of the exhaust and if it does so in such a way that it falls off you could be putting anyone behind you at risk.

Additionally it would be a *spectacular* MOT failure (and as Solar Mike states it would violate C&U regs) - so if you are stopped by the police or DVSA expect a [Vehicle Defect Rectification Notice](https://www.gov.uk/stopped-by-police-while-driving-your-rights/faults-with-your-vehicle) and 14 days to get it fixed and provide proof to the police that it has been done.

Comment: the real issue might be short arms and deep pockets...